# Diffidence, a false friend

Tags: meaning, etymology, semantic-shift

I’ve recently erroneously used the term [diffidence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diffidence) with the meaning of *distrust*.

Diffidence is one of the terms called [false friend](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/false-friend) and, as a matter of fact,  the same term in French [defiance](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%C3%A9fiance/22658?q=defiance#22538) and Italian [diffidenza](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/D/diffidenza.shtml) mean “distrust”.

They all derive from Latin diffidentia "mistrust, distrust, want of confidence” but, unlike in other languages, the term in English had a semantic change:

> [Original sense](https://www.etymonline.com/word/diffidence) (distrust of others) is obsolete; the modern sense is of "distrust of oneself, want of confidence in one's ability, worth, or fitness" (1650s), hence "retiring disposition, modest reserve."  (Etymonline)

Can anyone try to explain how this semantic change happened in English?

Comment: Does 'distrust in oneself' to 'modest' not bridge the gap for you?

Comment: @Mitch - it explains the modern sense, but not the disappearance of the original one.

Comment: What kind of evidence would you find persuasive? I can certainly track down early instances of the new meaning, but it's hard to find evidence of the absence, that is, "the disappearance of the original one."

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin - I agree, plus it’s a few century back. Probably the emergence of synonyms  made diffidence obsolete in its original meaning.

Comment: Another possibility is a case of the culture pivoting around the idea. If the nation's mores changed with respect to diffidence, as they did with terms like condescension, something had to give. Either the definition and usage had to change, or the sense of whether it was a compliment or an indictment.

Comment: @user067531 'distrust in oneself' is part of the original sense. From there to 'modest' is barely a half step.

Comment: @Mitch - yes, but you insist on the current sense while I am asking about the original one. Why did it disappear?

Comment: lexical shifts ... often not explainable

Comment: Interesting question. My WAG (wild ass guess) is that the answer lies in it being an uncommon word in English to begin with.  Occasional use combined with lack of good context leading to semantic shift.

Comment: @user067531 My mistake. Yes, I was in error in referring to 'distrust in oneself' as part of the original meaning. But looking again above 'diffidentia' has 'want of confidence'. It just doesn't seem that special to me, there's no big leap from mistrust in others to mistrust in oneself.

Comment: Incidentally, _defiance_ is also a false friend, as it means something else in English (the act of defying).

Comment: Usage, usage, usage. What else?

Comment: @Kris - what don’t you post an answer?

Comment: As the OP is about what words *diffidence* is a false friend for, the French *défiance* is not relevant because it is patently a different form. The English word relevant for the French *défiance* is "defiance", which @KateBunting mentioned.

Comment: The OED gives examples if the first meaning of *Lack of confidence or faith in someone or something; distrust; ... doubt.* from a1425, a1450, 1526, 1548, 1614, 1649, 1712, 1741, 1823, 1892, 2007. and of the second meaning of *Doubt in one's own ability, ... lack of self-confidence; modesty or shyness ...* from 1557, 1605, 1711, 1798, 1841, 1861, 1921, 1954, 2002. A glance at the intervals tends to suggest that the current meaning appeared come time in the late 18th century, the two ran together for about 100 years and the first meaning was then relegated in the early 20th century.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my best guess:

English has countless examples of pairs of words with similar meanings; in most cases, one word is derived from Latin (usually via French), and the other is derived from a Germanic root. Sometimes, there are more than two in each family, and the result is what one might call "semantic crowding" followed by words in the family either becoming more specific or more generic. This seems to be what happened in the case of 'diffidence.'

Derived from Latin: diffidence, confidence
Derived from Germanic root: mistrust, trust, distrust

Diffidence is now the opposite of one sense of confidence. It is no longer the opposite of trust because that word already had two opposites derived from the same root in mistrust and distrust. Diffidence is forced to specialize and loses its broader meaning, as do distrust and mistrust. Confidence, on the other hand, has only one possible synonym in trust, and this allows both to retain a broad semantic field without overlapping entirely.

Comment: Please restrict best guesses to 'comments'. And we've all had to get past the 50-point hurdle.

Comment: The OED gives *no* Germanic origins for 'diffidence': *Etymology: < classical Latin diffīdentia lack of confidence, distrust, in post-classical Latin also lack of religious faith (Vulgate) < diffīdent- , diffīdēns , present participle of diffīdere diffide v. + -ia -ia suffix1; compare -ence suffix.*